# Remove rows from dataframe that don't follow average trend

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to remove values from a dataframe of GPS co-ords that defer from a "smooth route".

A smooth route would be one with all values that are out of range of the overall trend.

I would like it to be simple and not use other large package (such as `scipy`). `

One issue is that the first few values may be incorrect so can't be used. The dataframe can be of any size rangeing for a couple of points to a few thousand. I believe it is more difficult with a smaller dataset.

Minimal Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 52.1, 1: 5.2, 2: 5.3, 3: 5.2, 4: 5.4, 5: 0.0, 6: 5.2}, 'b': {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 46.0, 5: 3.1, 6: 3.2}})

>>> df
     a     b
0  52.1  3.0
1  5.2   3.0
2  5.3   3.0
3  5.2   0.0
4  5.4  46.0
5  0.0   3.1
6  5.2   3.2
```

Desired output:

```
>>> df
     a     b
1  5.2   3.0
2  5.3   3.0
6  5.2   3.2
```

I have tried using z-score, and this doesn't always work for all use cases as the small changes in data don't get picked up.

Comment: You'll need to define "defer" and "smooth" for this to have a well-defined solution.

Comment: Do you have multiple ranges or you are sure about having only one range?

Comment: Another question: do you have like this pattern: 1,2,3,50,51? Where are the outliers, if you have multiple ranges? The range is with longer sequence, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean for your first question.... 
Second question I would say the range is with the longer sequence

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the top and bottom 10 quantiles:

```
>>> df[(df>=df.quantile(0.10)) & (df<=df.quantile(0.90))].dropna()
     a    b
1  5.2  3.0
2  5.3  3.0
6  5.2  3.2
```

You can adjust the quantiles as needed for your larger dataset.

Comment: What if there is no value out of range in the lower quantile. For instance, the values of column (b) between 1 - 7, or all entries have the same value?

Comment: I think his question is more about how to exclude the outliers in the data.

Comment: @not_speshal Thank you for your answer. What if there are no outliers in the data at all, good data is being removed?